# Push Notification in Titanium Android Application

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, titanium, appcelerator

I have my Titanium Application for Android and now I want to implement Push Notification for Android in Titanium. I have my back-end service which get all notifications for me but I don't have knowledge about Google Cloud Messaging and what are the relation between them (i.e Push Notification and GCM). Please Provide me guidelines and way how to do it. Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0):

Doing push notifications with Titanium is probably going to require a 3rd party service, most, if not all, are subscription fee based.

I've been looking to this myself for some planned future projects using either Titanium or Apache Cordova(Phone Gap).

The most popular recommendation I've been getting is [Urban Airship](http://urbanairship.com/) It looks like they have some pretty nice features, but I haven't looked much further into it than that.

Answer (score 0):

For Titanium, you can use this module (Open Source): https://github.com/liccowee/Google-Cloud-Messaging--Titanium-.

In examples, you see how to implement it in your app.